# How can I don't use sub query in checking the missing data

Tags: jquery, sql, subquery, nested-select

I have to write a query that find missing data, but I want it to write without any subqueries or nested SELECT (it finds the missing data and inserts it from a table to the one that has missing data).

The query is:

```sql
INSERT INTO Personal_tbl 
    SELECT * 
    FROM PersonalView 
    WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM Personal_tbl)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You would generally use `not exists` for such task:

```
insert into personal_tbl (...) -- enumerate the target columns here
select *                       -- and here as well
from personalview pv
where not exists (select 1 from personal_tbl pt where pt.pid = pv.pid)
```

I don't see why you wouldn't want to use a subquery for this. With an index on `personal_tbl(pid)`, this should be an efficient approach. But if you like, you can implement the same logic with a `left join`:

```
insert into personal_tbl (...)
select pv.*
from personalview pv
left join personal_tbl pt on pt.pid = pv.pid
where pt.pid is null
```

Comment: I have a problem with the join, it insert the missing data at the end of the table? do u know how i can fix that?

Comment: @SaraMoradi: I don't know what you mean. The query inserts the data into the table. There is no notion of beginning or end in the rows of the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Personal_tbl
SELECT Pv.*
FROM PersonalView Pv
INNER JOIN Personal_tbl pt ON  pt.PID <> Pv.PID
```

Comment: Best practice is to explicitly list the columns being inserted, and to explicitly list the columns being selected.